# Citation style for CS publications

Tags: soft-question, advice-request, citations

What is the recommended citation style for use with CS (and related) publications?

I tried looking at submissions at http://arxiv.org/archive/cs but all of them seem to use different citation styles.

I'm doing an academic project and I'm writing a project report for the same. So, is there a (possibly 'standard') citation style that is preferred over other citation styles (such as those listed at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia#Examples) for CS publications (like research papers, project reports, books, presentations etc.)?
Or, is it a matter of personal choice/preference (and sticking to it forever)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most CS conference publications use the ACM BibTeXstyle file (or the plain style file) to cite papers, and that constitutes the de facto 'style'. Different journals and conferences often prescribe their own citation format via a different BibTeX style.

So the short answer to your question is that there isn't a common style, and if you believe in using BibTex, then merely changing the style file can allow you to accommodate different styles.

Comment: A recent trend seems to be BibLaTeX instead of BibTeX (at least on [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex)), but this is largely unrelated to what is being asked.